# How to set default property in AOSP conditionally

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to set default NTP server (config_ntpServer) to none if build variant is user.

I saw that in order to do that, I need to edit overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml.

But how do I add the conditional part, e.g. if build variant is user, then set config_ntpServer to None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right way but you could try to:

1. copy the config.xml into your device tree.
2. change the config_ntpServer to none
3. add something like the following to your board.mk in your device tree:

   ```
   ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),user)
       PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/vendor/product/config.xml:overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
   endif
   ```